# Convert a special string format into dict?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to turn a string like this: 
`'word1-3,word2-4,word3-1,word4-2'`

into a dictionary like this: 
`{'word1': 3 , 'word2': 4 , 'word3' : 1 , 'word4' : 2}`

How can I do so?

Comment: Hello, Kosar, welcome to StackOveflow. Please familiarize yourself with the guidelines for [ask]. Generally, you want to give evidence that you've done *something* to try to solve this on your own. Questions that are perceived as bare "give me the codez" type will be received poorly.

Answer (score 3):

If the "-" and "," characters are only used as delimiters, then you can try something like this:

```
s = 'word1-3,word2-4,word3-1,word4-2'
d = dict(item.split('-') for item in s.split(','))
print(d) # >> {'word4': '2', 'word1': '3', 'word3': '1', 'word2': '4'}
```

Or using a dictionary comprehension and converting the values to integers:

```
s = 'word1-3,word2-4,word3-1,word4-2'
d = {pair[0]:int(pair[1]) for pair in [item.split('-') for item in s.split(',')]}
print(d) # >> {'word4': '2', 'word1': '3', 'word3': '1', 'word2': '4'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guess that you meant how to accomplish this with code, as python strings cannot accomplish this in most circumstances.

```
#import split from the re library
from re import split

#your example string
some_string = 'word1-3,word2-4,word3-1,word4-2'

#this will hold our values while we iterate through it
output_dict = {}

#split the some_string into a list of key value strings
for key_val_pair in split(r',', some_string):
    #split the key value pair into a key and value
    key_val_split = split(r'\-', key_val_pair)
    #append the value to the dict, indexed by the key
    output_dict[key_val_split[0]] = key_val_split[1]
```

output_dict will be as requested.